# ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111 "Connection refused")

Tags: mysql, linux, phpmyadmin, apache2

Пытался поставить на линукс phpmyadmin. Вначале была ошибка, что нет данного файла или каталога, сейчас жалуется на это. Только начал работать с БД. Как решить? И, если можно, объясните, из-за чего она появляется

Comment: попробуйте подключиться через tcp, а не через unix сокет.

Comment: MySQL включено? `ps aux | grep mysql` показывает больше одной строки?

Comment: Только одну. Выхлоп могу прислать

Comment: Тогда надо поднять `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start` или `service mysql start`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111 "Connection refused")

Проверить, если сервис `MySQL` вкл. команда:

```
$ ps aux | grep mysql
```

Если возвращает только одну строку, значит надо поднять сервис.

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

или

```
$ service mysql start
```